# Bootstrap 4: Dropdown in <td> not showing

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a dropdown in a table-element using Bootstrap 4 Framework. The inspector shows that the content from the WP-Database is loaded correctly, but they remain greyed out. Even if I click the button, that does not change. [image]

So basically, the dropdown options don't get displayed / aren't triggered. Where am I going wrong?

Actual code:

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Auswählen
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <?php
            foreach($players as $player):
                echo "<li class='dropdown-item'><a href='#'>$player->post_title</a></li>";
                endforeach;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what W3 school says.
"Add the .dropdown-menu class to a "div" element to actually build the dropdown menu."
I think you need to change "ul" into "div".

Comment: I tried it, not working. Is this a JavaScript problem maybe?

Comment: Please be sure to load bootstrap.min.js after dropdown element.

Comment: How can this be achieved? I'm enqueuing the script in my functions.php with the $in_footer=true. Yet neither the bootstrap.min.js nor the popper.min.js are loaded as scripts in the footer in my browser. As a matter of fact, i can't find them at all even with the search function. The rest of the scripts that are in the same file are loaded just fine. I added the code for enqueuing up above.

Comment: The problem has been resolved during the time being. There where multiple causes. First, my mozilla settings prevented me from loading external cookies and scripts from the CDN. I fixed by changing the settings back to Default. Second, the function for enqueuing was missing an argument, preventing the loading itself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any questions would be glad for me.